# 99 fair coin and 1 coin that has 50% chance of being double headed

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

A hat contains 100 coins, 99 of them are guaranteed to be fair and 1 that has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to be double-headed. A coin is randomly chosen at random and flipped 7 times. If it landed heads each time what is the probability that one of the coins is double-headed?

---

My approach:

Apply Bayes:

P(A) = the probability of it being double-headed.

P(B) = the probability of making 7 heads.

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}$

$P(A) = \frac{1}{100}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{200}$

$P(B|A) = 1$

$P(B) = (\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{100}1 + \frac{99}{100}\frac{1}{2^7}) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{100}{100}\frac{1}{2^7} = \frac{327}{25600}$

$P(A|B) = \frac{\frac{1}{200}}{\frac{327}{25600}} = \frac{128}{327} \approx 39.14\%$

Comment: A small matter of notation: I would write something like, "$B$ is the event of making 7 heads." It's reasonably obvious that that's what you *wanted* to say when you wrote, "P(B) = the probability of making 7 heads," but it's not actually the same statement. When you want to say what $P(B\mid A)$ is equal to, you want to know exactly what $A$ and $B$ are, not what $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have computed is the probability that *the coin you randomly chose*
is double-headed.

The problem statement asks you to find the
probability that *one of the coins* is double-headed.
The double-headed coin does not need to be the one you chose.

Before you chose the coin and flipped it seven times, the chance that one of the coins was double-headed was $1/2.$ You are less likely to get seven heads in your first seven flips if there is no double-headed coin in the hat, so the fact that the coin landed heads seven times should make it more likely that there is a double-headed coin. That is, your answer should be greater than $1/2.$

Comment: Yeah, I see your point.  It's a really poorly phrased question.  I just went with the OP's interpretation but a literal reading of the question indicates your interpretation is the precise one.

Answer (score 2):

Your work is correct, but only if we assume that the only other possibility for the coin that has a $1/2$ probability of being double-headed is that it is fair.  This is not explicitly stated in the question.  In other words, it could be double-headed, *or* it could be double-tailed.  Or it could be biased in some other way.  If it is either double-headed or it is fair, and either is equally likely, then your computation is correct.

Comment: It's correct working for a problem that wasn't posed. They were supposed to find the probability of "one of the coins" having two heads.

Comment: Regarding the problem OP solved, on the one hand it's a fairly obvious interpretation to assume the last coin is fair with probability $1/2.$ On the other hand I appreciate the critique and find it annoying that a problem like this asks for this kind of mind-reading of the author's intent when it would have been very simple to remove that ambiguity.